# Get value of text inside span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-framework, jquery-events

I am working with Flexigrid plugin with JQuery. Ok so I have a div with two span elements, they would contain the text/display text for the buttons that flexigrid provides. The problem is, there is no mechanism to add ids to those buttons, except for adding different text.

```
<div class="tdiv2>  
    <div class="fbutton">
        <div>
            <span class="view" style="padding-left: 20px;">Add</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fbutton">
        <div>
            <span class="view" style="padding-left: 20px;">Delete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how the buttons are arranged. So onclick of that button, I get the text inside the span, as Add and Delete. Now I want to add a class tag to that span, to differentiate between the active button and the other one.

So I came up with the idea, that if I could get span-text that matches to the text being returned, I could add the class to that span.

But when I do

```
alert($('.tDiv2 span').html());
```

I am only getting the text of the first span and not the second one. Could somebody help me with getting the html of both spans and not just the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this >

```
$('.tDiv2 span').each(function(index, el) { alert($(el).html()); });
```

Comment: Hello when I tried your code, it gives me this error. "el.html is not a function"

Comment: It still is giving me the same error. I just looked up the jquery documentation, which one would be the collection?? I understand function would be the callback. "jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )"

Comment: The collection would be the object on which it is called. In your case it would be `$('.tDiv2 span')`. According the documentation, you need to pass a callback function with 2 parameters. Can you alert `$('.tDiv2 span').length` and see how many objects it has?

Comment: Ok I just passed "el" and not "el.html()", it returned object span element twice

Comment: just corrected it. `el` is basically an dom element, not an jQuery element. So we wrapped it around $() to get the jQuery obj. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery automatically selects the first element in a series if you try to get a property like html or text from it. to get the second (or any number) try:

```
alert($('.tDiv2 span').eq(1).html()); //returns 2nd element's html content
```

You can substitute any 0 based index in for 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need [each](http://api.jquery.com/each).

`$('.tDiv2 span')each(function(node){ alert(node.html()); });`

However, I would like to point out that this approach is likely to cause accessibility problems for screen reader users.  If you absolutely must re-invent buttons for some reason, then use [ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php) attributes so that your blind visitors have some hope of getting it to work right.